# Why NOT IN operator in SQL filters out null values also?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query like this:

```
select * 
from table 
where name not in ("Ram", "Lakshman", "Sita")
```

I have this table which I run the `SELECT` on:

| Name | Salary | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | 100000 | ABC. |
| Ram | 200000 | CDE. |
|  | 300000 | DEF. |

This query returns a data set with zero rows. Why did the 1st and 3rd row get skipped?

Comment: Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL`, which is treated as "false" in a `WHERE` clause.  That is how SQL works.  You need to learn about `NULL`.

Comment: Any use of `null` needs to be read as `unknown` - then it makes perfect sense as you can't *know* an unknown values is not in your data set as it's `unknown`.